# input field pops over the inner shadow css

Tags: html, css

I have a simple box with overflow and would like to show that it is scrollable by adding a shadow on the bottom. It works, but the problem is that I have some input fields which pop over the shadow, which doesn't look nice. Setting `z-index` doesn't help and I don't know any other way to approach this. Here is a snippet to give you an idea of how it looks:

```css
#box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px -6px 8px #888888 inset;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id= "box">
  Some text<br>This text is so good<br>OMG this text is just epic<br>
  No way, more text?<br>Wow, this text is drivig me crazy<br>
  <input><br>
  More text here as well.
</div>
```

Comment: everything pop over the shadow even the text but since the text is having the same color as the shadow you cannot notice it

Comment: add `background: transparent` to the input and see the difference

Comment: `<input>` is an empty tag (replaced element)  and as such ahs no closing tag. `</input>` as such is invalid as it does not exist!

Comment: @tacoshy True, my fault. I have edited that. Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: @TemaniAfif `background: transparent` seems like a cheat rather than an actual fix considering what you have said in your first comment

Comment: it's not a fix, it's to show you the issue I talked about in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the shadow on top of the content we can create a visual element that is layed out above content and has the shadow.

We can achieve that with a pseudo element, but because of the `overflow` attribute, the shadow scrolls with the content. To get around that, we can create an inner wrapper-element with the `overflow` and keep the shadow element outside.

Since the shadow element now lays on top of everything, we can't actually scroll or select the input element. `pointer-events: none;` fixes that:

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
}
#box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px -6px 8px #888888 inset;
}
.box-inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
    Some text<br>This text is so good<br>OMG this text is just epic<br>
    No way, more text?<br>Wow, this text is drivig me crazy<br>
    <input /><br>
    More text here as well.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that is way more complicated than I thought it should be, but you have nailed it. Thanks a lot. I would also add `width: 500px;` to `box-inner` just to make the scroll bar match with the edge of the box